# Append incoming message to ChatViewController collectionview (XMPPFramework+JSQMessagesViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, xmppframework, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm currently developing a chat app for iOS using XMPPFramework and JSQMessagesViewController, i'm new to all of this so bear with me.

I got the XMPP Server up and running, I can see sent and incoming message through the console log, what I am trying to do is to append/display incoming message to the collectionView UI (JSQMessagesViewController).

so far what I did was call a viewcontroller func from the app delegate
here's the code in the app delegate for the incoming message

```
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream!, didReceive message: XMPPMessage!) {
    print("Did received message \(message)")
    if message.isChatMessageWithBody() {
      chatView.receiveMessage(passMessage: message.stringValue)
    }
}
```

the ViewController method

```
func receiveMessage(passMessage: String!) {
    let receivedMessage = JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderDisplayName, text: passMessage)
    self.messages.append(receivedMessage!)
    self.finishReceivingMessage(animated: true)
    JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageReceivedSound()
}
```

with this approach, the app crashes on incoming message and I'm getting the unexpected nil value error from the senderId.
I cant seem to work this out.
please advise
Thank you.

Comment: I think you should try out the JSQ example from github.  There are some delegate methods you need to implement in your jsqmessagesviewcontroller subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the issue is that you have not setup your `JSQMessagesViewController` with all its required delegate methods. I would check out [this link](https://macmedan.github.io/jekyll/update/2016/11/20/Minimal-JSQMessagesViewController-Using-Swift-3.html) for the bear minimum of what you have to do to get JSQ working.

Also I would warn of force unwrapping optionals ( which is where you use the `!` after a variable) So I would suggest changing this:

```
func receiveMessage(passMessage: String!) {
  let receivedMessage = JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderDisplayName, text: passMessage)
  self.messages.append(receivedMessage!)
  self.finishReceivingMessage(animated: true)
  JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageReceivedSound()
}
```

To something more like this:

```
func receiveMessage(passMessage: String) {
  guard let receivedMessage = JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderDisplayName, text: passMessage) else {
    AssertionFailure("Could not get message")
    return
  }
  self.messages.append(receivedMessage)
  self.finishReceivingMessage(animated: true)
  JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageReceivedSound()
}
```

let me know if you have more questions.